# Subharmonic inequality 4

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

Problem:
If i have a subharmonic function $u$ on $D$ the unit disc, then for any two smaller radius $r_1\leq r_2$ we have $$\int_0^{2\pi}u(r_1e^{i\varphi})d\varphi\leq \int_0^{2\pi}u(r_2e^{i\varphi})d\varphi$$

Comment: Can we assume the converse inequality and reach a contradiction using maximum principle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\m[2]{\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}#1\left(#2 e^{it}\right)\,dt}$

Say $v$ is the solution to a certain Dirichlet problem: $v$ is harmonic in $|z|<r_2$ and $v(z)=u(z)$ for $|z|=r_2$. Then one of the basic properties of subharmonic functions says that $$u(z)\le v(z)\quad(|z|<r_2);$$in fact this is why they're called "subharmonic". So
$$\begin{align}\m{u}{r_1}&\le\m{v}{r_1}
\\&=v(0)
\\&=\m{v}{r_2}
\\&=\m{u}{r_2}.\end{align}$$

Comment: You're doing something fancy there with the MathJax, but there's a $dt$ by itself on the last line.

Comment: @zhw. Thanks. Nothing to do with fancy MathJax, the problem is just that it didn't fit on one line.

Comment: Well fancy for me. I'm not familiar with \newcommand etc.

Comment: @zhw. newcommand is very useful. Here it meant I only had to type \frac 1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(re^{it})\,dt once. TeX is a programming language, and in general in programming subroutines are regarded as preferable to repeated code for various reasons. Any book on TeX will advise you to use macros for all sorts of reasons, over and above laziness. At first it seems like a lot of trouble but you soon realize taking the time to define a few macros actually saves a lot of time in total.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've learned the Tex I know on the run, without any manual, so I'm pretty rough around the edges. I have written all sorts of macros, for example control f brings up \frac{}{}, but they're homemade things done in Quickeys.